# Firebase query 2 same methods one is working,other not

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I got 2 same methods in one I declare string in Query and on another I declare it thru variable, but when I run apk the one I declare string inside Query works but the other does not.

First method:

```
 private void randomtest() {

    Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users").orderByChild("username").equalTo("darkarcher5");
    query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot users : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                User user = users.getValue(User.class);
                Log.e("username", user.getUsername());
                Log.e("password", user.getPassword());
                userList.add(user);
            }
            txtViewPass.setText(userList.get(0).getUsername());

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

}
```

Second method:

```
private  void neRandomTest() {
    if (username != null) {
        Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("user").orderByChild("username").equalTo(username);
        query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot users : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    User user = users.getValue(User.class);
                    Log.e("username", user.getUsername());
                    Log.e("password", user.getPassword());
                    userList.add(user);
                }
                txtViewPass.setText(userList.get(0).getUsername());

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Error given by second method: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0

Comment: Verify that the userList is not empty before accessing a value in your code.

Answer (score 1):

In your first method, your query is referencing on the "**users**" node while on your second method your query is referencing on the "**user**" node. If I am correct you are trying to connect to "user" node in second method which is not available in the firebase database. That's why indexoutofbounds.

Try using this:

```
private  void neRandomTest() {
if (username != null) {
    //Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("user").orderByChild("username").equalTo(username);

    Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users").orderByChild("username").equalTo(username);
    query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot users : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                User user = users.getValue(User.class);
                Log.e("username", user.getUsername());
                Log.e("password", user.getPassword());
                userList.add(user);
            }
            txtViewPass.setText(userList.get(0).getUsername());

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
}
```